# How can I easily replace special characters with rvest-friendly UTF-8 (hex.)

Tags: r, unicode, encoding, utf-8, rvest

I need to substitute special characters like é and â with strings like %C3%A9, %C3%A2. This is because an url with a special character will work in a browser, but not with R's `rvest::read_html()` function - it requires the "%C3%A9" style strings in place of the special characters.

Presently, I am having to wait until I get an error due to a special character being in a url, then I have to manually look up the special character's equivalent value [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/), then gsub it:

```
  list_of_urls %>% 
  gsub("é", "%C3%A9", .) %>% 
  gsub("â", "%C3%A2", .) %>% 
  gsub("ç", "%C3%A7", .) %>% 
  gsub("á", "%C3%A1", .)
```

Is there an R function that does this for all special characters automatically (i.e. without all the gsubs for individual characters) ?

For example, the string "glaçage" should become "gla%C3%A7age"

And the string "café" should become "caf%C3%A9"

Comment: You could use `iconv(yourstrings, to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")` if you just want non-accented versions of the words, or the `stringi` package has lots of encoding help which will probably help you any way you need. You should update your question with examples that can be reproduced, otherwise it is difficult to help. Thanks :)

Comment: I have included some examples. As for stringi, I tried a couple of stringi functions but couldn't get any to work (it's entirely possible I wasn't applying them correctly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `URLencode` in `utils`? Here is how it works on your example:

```
> library(utils)
> URLencode("glaçage")
[1] "gla%E7age"
> z <- URLencode("glaçage")
> URLdecode(z)
[1] "glaçage"
```

Second example:

```
> URLencode("café")
[1] "caf%E9"
```

Comment: I get [1] "gla%C3%A7age" and [1] "caf%C3%A9" for your two encode calls. On Mac with current R version.

Comment: Just ran command again on 3.4.3 and 3.4.4 in R and RStudio and got the same as above. Is there a difference in encoding btwn OS? Have not heard of that yet... interesting.

Comment: Windoze is often an oddball on encoding.